# Como declarar corretamente dependência Server Runtime ou provided do Wildfly no Gradle

Tags: java, java-ee, wildfly, gradle

Possuo uma projeto Java para web sendo desenvolvido para rodar no Wildfly, utilizando a IDE Eclipse.
Essa aplicação utiliza JPA, JTA, JSF e CDI a princípio, porém irá utilizar outros recursos do Java EE no futuro.
O controle de dependências desse projeto é feito pelo Gradle, porém como podem observar no `build.gradle` abaixo, eu não declaro nenhuma das dependências já presentes no Wildfly:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Arch Project', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Portanto, para adicionar as dependências do Java EE eu adiciono o uma *library* do tipo *Server Runtime* em meu projeto, em outras palavras, clico com o botão direito em meu projeto -> *Configure Build Path* -> *Add Libraries*, seleciono *Server Runtmime* e por final, seleciono o *server* Wildfly que configurei no meu Eclipse.

A configuração acima deixa meu projeto com 3 bibliotecas

- JRE System Library
- Gradle Dependencies (vazia)
- Wildfly 8.2 Runtime

### Problema

Deste modo, consigo executar minha aplicação no Wildfly (botão direito no projeto -> *Run As* -> *Run on Server*, porém, se eu tentar construir meu *.war* utilizando o gradle através do comando *gradle war*, ele obviamente dá erro, acusando que as classes do Wildfly não estão no classpath.

### Soluções

1. Declarar as dependências do JPA, JTA, JSF e CDI com escopo `provided` no `build.gradle`:

   - Pró: Já vi algo parecido em projetos maven e deixa claro pros outros desenvolvedores quais dependências são utilizadas.
   - Contra: Para evitar bugs terei que me atentar às versões das APIs utilizadas pelo Wildfly, e a cada nova dependência, terei que abrir a documentação do Wildfly e buscar pela versão correta do jar, para adicionar a mesma versão como dependência `provided` em meu gradle.
2. De alguma forma semelhante ao Eclipse, adicionar a dependência de um `server runtime` ao meu build.gradle.

   - Pró: Caso funcione corretamente, terei certeza de que estou utilizando as mesmas bibliotecas que serão buscadas quando a aplicação estiver rodando no servidor, evitando surpresas de versões diferentes ou até mesmo os famosos `ClassNotFoundException` por ter desenvolvido com APIs mais modernas das que estão no Wildfly.
   - Contra: Não sei sequer se isso é possível, e se for, acredito que cada usuário que baixar o projeto em sua máquina, terá que manualmente configurar o caminho do Wildfly para que o Gradle possa encontrar.

Gostaria de saber qual a solução é mais adequada, e caso seja a segunda, como seria realizada essa configuração.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enquanto ambas as soluções parecem ser aceitáveis, a segunda inclui uma dependência externa (implícita) ao IDE.  Dessa forma, a primeira solução me parece a mais adequada.

Sobre as versões das APIs utilizadas pelo Wildfly, eu não me preocuparia muito com isso. Na verdade, para os serviços do Java EE você geralmente só precisa depender das interfaces / APIs.

Em muitos projetos uma simples dependência para [javaee-api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0#gradle) é suficiente:

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}

dependencies {
    provided 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
}
```

Para evitar problemas com diferenças de versões entre algumas APIs presentes simultaneamente na JVM (Java SE) e no seu servidor de aplicação (Java EE) é interessante também configurar a [Java EE Endorsed Api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-endorsed-api/7.0#gradle). Para mais informações sobre como fazer isso no gradle veja [essa postagem](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/compile_classpath_problem_j2se_j2ee).

Para APIs individuais do Java EE, veja [essa listagem](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Java+EE+7+Maven+Coordinates).

---

É claro que eventualmente você pode querer utilizar APIs não padronizadas, e.g., anotações específicas do [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/). Nesse caso você também precisará incluir dependências `provided` para as bibliotecas. Esses são os casos mais difíceis de administrar (conforme a conclusão que você chegou na pergunta) pois pode haver quebra de compatibilidade caso as configurações do `graddle` não reflitam a exata realidade do servidor de aplicação. O ideal é reduzir a quantidade de dependências desse tipo. Aquelas dependências que forem estritamente necessárias devem ficar destacadas; é interessante também criar mecanismos para te ajudar a atualizar versões (e.g., propriedades para versões bem destacadas ao estilo `maven`).

Comment: Olá Anthony! Agradeço pela resposta.

Comment: Eu não conhecia essa dependência do `javaee-api`, ela realmente resolve muitos dos problemas que eu teria. A segunda opção me pareceu a mais frágil mesmo, de qualquer forma iria necessitar de parametrização pro Wildfly no classpath do usuário.
Sou novo em gradle e ainda não utilizei `sourceSets` e `configurations`. Você poderia me dar uma breve explicação do que eles fazem nessa configuração específica? De qualquer modo, aceitarei sua resposta e agradeço novamente pela ótima explicação.

Comment: Ela emula a configuração `provided` do Maven. Basicamente isso cria uma árvore de dependências a parte (chamada `provided`) e adiciona ao Classpath (nesse caso, de compilação e runtime, tanto para testes quanto para a aplicação principal. Pode não ser exatamente seu caso).

Comment: Perfeito. Acredito que eu precisarei sim, pois os testes unitários serão o próximo passo. Além disso, irei ler à respeito da endorsed API, já vi em alguns lugares mas eu não sabia do que se tratava (e que era tão importante). Obrigado Anthony.